# How to simulate Fortran's "replace" equivalent for MPI's file_open

Tags: io, fortran, mpi

I have been trying to write a subroutine that will use MPI to write files to use in a large code. This subroutine will be called many times throughout the code, which is pretty huge, so I'm trying to make it as fast as possible. One problem I'm facing is how to replicate Fortran's "replace" status (when opening a file using fortran). That is, I'm having difficulty setting up MPI in a way that creates the file if it doesn't exist or that replaces it if it exists. Is there a preferred way to do that? I find it odd the MPI does not have a mode for that.

Here's a MWE:

```
PROGRAM main
    use mpi
    integer ierr, i, global_rank, BUFSIZE, thefile
    integer, parameter :: nx=200, ny=200, nz=10
    integer, dimension(nx,ny,nz) :: uu, vv, ww
    integer :: np
    integer(kind=MPI_OFFSET_KIND) disp
    bufsize=size(uu)
    call MPI_INIT(ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, np, ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, global_rank, ierr)
    do i = 1, nx
        uu(i,:,:) = i
    enddo
    do i = 1, ny
        vv(:,i,:) = i
    enddo
    do i = 1, nz
        ww(:,:,i) = i + nz*global_rank
    enddo
    call MPI_FILE_OPEN(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 'testfile.bin', &
                       MPI_MODE_WRONLY + MPI_MODE_CREATE + MPI_MODE_EXCL, &
                       MPI_INFO_NULL, thefile, ierr)
    print*,ierrr
    disp = global_rank * BUFSIZE * 4 ! 4 byte integers
    call MPI_FILE_SET_VIEW(thefile, disp, MPI_INTEGER, &
                           MPI_INTEGER, 'native', &
                           MPI_INFO_NULL, ierr)
    call MPI_FILE_WRITE(thefile, uu, BUFSIZE, MPI_INTEGER, &
                        MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)


    disp = np*bufsize*4 + global_rank * BUFSIZE * 4
    call MPI_FILE_SET_VIEW(thefile, disp, MPI_INTEGER, &
                           MPI_INTEGER, 'native', &
                           MPI_INFO_NULL, ierr)
    call MPI_FILE_WRITE(thefile, vv, BUFSIZE, MPI_INTEGER, &
                        MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)


    disp = 2*np*bufsize*4 + global_rank * BUFSIZE * 4
    call MPI_FILE_SET_VIEW(thefile, disp, MPI_INTEGER, &
                           MPI_INTEGER, 'native', &
                           MPI_INFO_NULL, ierr)
    call MPI_FILE_WRITE(thefile, ww, BUFSIZE, MPI_INTEGER, &
                        MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)

    call MPI_FILE_CLOSE(thefile, ierr)
    call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

END PROGRAM main
```

P.S.: I have stumbled some similar questions in C, but I couldn't make anything that claimed to be a solution work in Fortran (perhaps due to my ignorance in C).

Comment: I agree that it is a little odd there isn't an MPI call or option for this, but if there is it's escaped me.  I suppose you could just insert a line of Fortran for one process to execute to make the file replacement ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `MPI_FILE_TRUNCATE` in the MPI standard.

Feel free to ask for it in the [Mailing list](https://lists.mpi-forum.org/mailman/listinfo/mpi-comments).

Meanwhile, you can unconditionally `MPI_File_delete()` and ignore the `MPI_ERR_NO_SUCH_FILE` error code.